# Strange compiler error when counting letters

Tags: c++

i made a progra which sum the occurences of a letter in a string , but i get a strange error, which i can't understand.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum=0;
    string sir;
    vector<int> num;
    vector<std::string> letters{"a","b","c","d","e","f","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"};
    getline(cin,sir);
    for(int i = 0; i < letters.size(); i++) {
       sum = std::count(sir.begin(),sir.end(), letters[i]);

    num.push_back(sum);
    sum=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and here ar the errors :

```
    c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h||In function 'typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type std::count(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Tp = std::basic_string<char>, typename std::iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::difference_type = int]':|
E:\c\Watermelon\main.cpp:15|58|instantiated from here|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4591|error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = char*, _Container = std::basic_string<char>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = char&]() == __value'|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h|4591|note: candidates are:|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\functional|2233|note: template<class _Res, class ... _Args> bool std::operator==(std::nullptr_t, const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\functional|2227|note: template<class _Res, class ... _Args> bool std::operator==(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&, std::nullptr_t)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\tuple|575|note: template<class ... _TElements, class ... _UElements> bool std::operator==(const std::tuple<_TElements ...>&, const std::tuple<_Elements ...>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|5322|note: template<class _RealType> bool std::operator==(const std::piecewise_linear_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::piecewise_linear_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|5080|note: template<class _RealType> bool std::operator==(const std::piecewise_constant_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::piecewise_constant_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|4841|note: template<class _IntType> bool std::operator==(const std::discrete_distribution<_IntType>&, const std::discrete_distribution<_IntType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|4609|note: template<class _RealType> bool std::operator==(const std::extreme_value_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::extreme_value_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|4434|note: template<class _RealType> bool std::operator==(const std::weibull_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::weibull_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|4259|note: template<class _RealType> bool std::operator==(const std::exponential_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::exponential_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|2459|note: template<class _RealType1> bool std::operator==(const std::gamma_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::gamma_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|3715|note: template<class _IntType> bool std::operator==(const std::geometric_distribution<_IntType>&, const std::geometric_distribution<_IntType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.tcc|1684|note: template<class _RealType1> bool std::operator==(const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::normal_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|3337|note: bool std::operator==(const std::bernoulli_distribution&, const std::bernoulli_distribution&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|3337|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'char' to 'const std::bernoulli_distribution&'|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|2798|note: template<class _RealType> bool std::operator==(const std::cauchy_distribution<_RealType>&, const std::cauchy_distribution<_RealType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|1906|note: template<class _IntType> bool std::operator==(const std::uniform_real_distribution<_IntType>&, const std::uniform_real_distribution<_IntType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\random.h|1725|note: template<class _IntType> bool std::operator==(const std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>&, const std::uniform_int_distribution<_IntType>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h|1273|note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\streambuf_iterator.h|194|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits> bool std::operator==(const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2460|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2448|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2434|note: template<class _CharT> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_Tp>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h|2427|note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator==(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\allocator.h|127|note: template<class _Tp> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_Tp1>&, const std::allocator<_Tp1>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\allocator.h|122|note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator==(const std::allocator<_T1>&, const std::allocator<_T2>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|1031|note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|1025|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|335|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|285|note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator==(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h|201|note: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator==(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\postypes.h|218|note: template<class _StateT> bool std::operator==(const std::fpos<_StateT>&, const std::fpos<_StateT>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\ext\new_allocator.h|123|note: template<class _Tp> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&, const __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<_Tp>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|805|note: template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)|
c:\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.2\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h|799|note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator==(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)|
||=== Build finished: 36 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value_type` of `sir` is `char`, but `letters[i]` is `std::string`. You can't compare a string with a char. Try the following instead:

```
vector<char> letters{'a','b','c','d','e','f','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
```

Comment: You might want to explain why `sir` is `char` when it's declared as `string sir;`

Comment: @CodyGray: I didn't say `sir` is `char`.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. You said that `value_type` of `sir` is `char`. I figured you'd know what you wrote. I figured that would still be potentially confusing for someone asking this question. Maybe not. I wasn't quibbling with the accuracy of your response...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a homework excersise.

You are marking it rather complicated. Try the following

1. Create an array of length 26, initialise all values to zero.
2. Get the line.
3. Take each character in turn. Make it lower case. Check if between a-z. Convert a->0, b->1 etc
4. Increment the corresponding integer in the array created in 1

You can then print out the array with the corresponding number of letters found in the line.

Comment: A better solution is always appreciated/helpful, but if you're right about this being homework, it would also be educational for him to understand why the code that he's written isn't working.

Comment: @cody - Was going to but ybungalobill beat me to it. ddacot - we know it is homework as we done similar exercises at Uni ourselves.

Comment: @EdHeal i'm learning c++ by my self, at school we learn pascal, and if i solve such an exercise this doesn't mean that it's a homework. As i see you know too much. :)